# How to prove Schwarz reflection principle?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is non-vanishing and continuous on a closed unit disk that is holomorphic in the interior $D$. Show that if

$\lvert f(z) \rvert = 1$ whenever $\lvert z \rvert = 1$

then $f$ is constant.

I'm not sure where to start with this one or how to go about this proof at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this question related to the [Schwarz reflection principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle)?

Answer (score 2):

Since $|f|$ is non-vanishing, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(z)|>M$ for all $z \in \bar D$.

Define $f(z)=\frac{1}{f(\frac{1}{\bar z})}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}-D$. Note that if $z \in \mathbb{C}-D$, then $\frac{1}{z} \in D$.

We claim that  $f$ is bounded and entire. then it is a constant function.

You can easily check that $|f|$ is bounded, and $f$ is holomorphic in D and $\mathbb{C}-D$

It suffices to show that $f$ is holomorphic on boundary ($|z|=1$)

Apply Morera's theorem !

Comment: You can't just redefine $f$ like you do... did you mean using a new name $g$ from line 2 on?

Comment: @vonbrand $f$ is originally not defined for $z$ outside the unit disc. Ryuichi is defining an extension of the given $f$. It's common abuse of notation to keep the same name for the extended function.

Comment: @mrf, no coffee yet. Sorry.